# Bulk Edit Users In Datazen

Tags: datazen-server

I'm trying to update the email addresses for about 600 users in Datazen Server v3. I tried importing a csv file from an Active Directory data dump and using the Batch Create Users import from the Home Page, but I got a unique constraint violation from the usernames with existing accounts.

This would be a fairly simple update in SQL, but I don't know how to access the data (nor do I think I can). Does anyone know of a way to bulk update user records? And if not, is there a way to bulk delete users so I can reimport them?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Still working on this. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: It looks like Datazen is not a very common tag. Are there related technology terms you can use? That might help to get this question some exposure.

Comment: :-) I wish. It seems to be a fairly specific application. I figured SO was my best shot in the dark. I haven't been able to fix this yet, but this project has kinda been put aside for the moment. I'll probably end up fixing my users manually.

Comment: I just wish I got my 50 point Bounty back. :-)